# Change duration of sublayer.show()

Tags: cartodb

When using `sublayer.show()` is there any way to set how long the transition takes?  https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/api-methods/#layershow

Manually stepping down the opacity seems not to work give that `.setOpacity()` is not available for sublayers.

Thanks!

EDIT:  I guess I could try adding css animations directly to the `.leaflet-tile` dom objs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [a `setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to the event. In relation to the opacity issue, you can use `setCartoCSS` and change the opacity property of your layer. For instance, if you have a points layer, you will need to change the `marker-opacity` property.

Comment: I'm looking to do slow cross fades between layers.  I'll definitely try out the setCartoCSS opacity changes.  I hesitated to do so before as it seemed it'd have to download new images for every step (since they filled in polygons are prerendered) and that would ruin the slow transition on slow connections.  Failing that I suppose I can always just learn how to assemble it on individual added layers.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: After trying it with the CSS call it seems the images load too slowly to be of much use for a real fade.  Thanks though.